How to Integrate .net core application to see logs in Azure Kubernates Cluster container insights
How can we integrate to see logs of our .net core API application in deployed Azure kubernates cluster container insights. what are all the code changes to be done to see errors and exceptions in container insights.
I got to know that WriteTo.Console() , console logs will be directly captured in runtime by kubernates cluster. So, what changes need to be done in .net core API application.

You do not have to do any code changes.
Just use any logging framework in your application that logs to your K8 pods file system( I think, by default it logs to your /usr/logs directory).
Go to Azure portal, navigate to your AKS resource, then go to the app insight blade on the left hand side and enable the logs.
You should be able to see the logs.
AKS automatically fetches your logs from the local log directory.
